# fine tuning my lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a simple lightbox with code like this:

jquery code:

```
var $overlay =$('<div class="overlay"></div>');

$('body').append($overlay);

$('img').click(function(){
$overlay.show();
});
```

css:

```
   .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
    display:none;
position: absolute;
top:0;
    }
```

This is obviously very simple I haven't wrote much code except the overlay that will appear when the image is clicked and triggers the lightbox.

Here are my questions:

1. My webpage is longer than the screen, what code could I use to stop the screen scrolling when my lightbox is triggered.
2. Is it possible to set the lightbox $overlay to only fill the screen in view. So only take up the part of the webpage in the current screen view. I have images spread out over webpages and I when are a lightbox is triggered I would like it to fill only that part of the screen.

Comment: We can't help you without code

Comment: ok i was looking for direction but cool I'll add some code now

Comment: agreed I've changed my post I'm getting stressed out trying to learn I look at my question edited some bits. I would just like someone to say hey explain this and then I'll help you and of course I will make changes

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to post an answer hopefully it will help you.
First things first, your JavaScript. From the JS you posted, it looks like you are using a different `.overlay` for each image. Not needed.
Simply make one overlay like so:

```
<div class="overlay"><img src="#" width="500"/></div>
```

Then, set the images `src` when you click on an image on your webpage:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');//Gets the image you clicked on src
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();//Fades in the overlay
    $('.overlay img').attr('src',src).css('margin-top',($(window).height() - $('.overlay img').height()-20)/2);//Sets the overlay image to the correct source, and centers the image. -20 is for the border
});
$('.overlay').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();// And fades out the overlay on click
});
```

Simple and easy. Now to your actual question.
How you are going to achieve what you want is with CSS.
First, set the body and html's height and width to 100%, and remove the margin. This stops overlay from making scroll bars:

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Then, to make overlay appear over the image you clicked, change `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`:

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Add a little more CSS to make it look pretty:

```
.overlay img{
    border-radius:5px;
    border:10px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
```

And Bang!

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ou670tj0/2/show)

[image: tada!!!]

### [Make sure you check out the coding in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ou670tj0/2/)

Comment: thanks alot for writing this, I'm not very good at jquery or javascript yet. If you have any spare time could you possibly explain that code. Of course I'm going to go away and look at it. But again thanks alot

Comment: @troybeckett the JS isn't that complicated, just play around with it and you should figure it out. also, when you find an answer that works for you, mark it as accepted with the little check mark beside it :D